# swift function or closure with pre-filled parameter

Tags: swift2

I have a class that takes a completion handler. Can I pre-fill some the parameters? The completion handler is a function itself rather than a closure.

```
func completionHandler(value: Int, value2: Int)
{
  print(value + value2)
}

func run() {
 let handler = completionHandler
 handler(9, value2: 7) //runs the handler
 someinstance.handler = handler //someinstance will eventually run the handler

 let handler2 = completionHandler(9) //is this possible?
 someinstance2.handler = handler2    //is this possible?

 someinstance3.handler = { a,b in return a+b } //also fine
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, technically, define a handler for you completion handler, for cases when you want to make use of a default value for `value` or `value2` in `completionHandler`.

```
func completionHandler(value: Int, _ value2: Int) {
    print(value + value2)
}

func defaultValueHandler(defaultValue: Int? = nil, defaultValue2: Int? = nil) -> ((Int) -> ()) {
    if let defaultValue2 = defaultValue2 {
        return { value in completionHandler(value, defaultValue2) }
    }
    else if let defaultValue = defaultValue {
        return { value in completionHandler(defaultValue, value) }
    }
    return { _ in print("Invalid use: supply a single non-nil default value.") }
}

var handler = defaultValueHandler(9)                  // default value for 'value'
handler(5) // calls foo(9, 5), prints 14

handler = defaultValueHandler(nil, defaultValue2: 11) // default value for 'value2'
handler(5) // calls foo(5, 11), prints 16
```

The use of this is, for your case, probably limited in practice. The `handler` closure instance above will be of type `(Int) -> ()` as compared to e.g. `completionHandler` function which is of type `(Int, Int) -> ()`. So if `someinstance.handler` (in your example) expects the latter, you'll be in trouble.

Now, you could modify `defaultValueHandler(..)` to return closures of type `(Int, Int) -> ()`, but then you'll need to supply calls to the resulting handling closure with two arguments, where one argument will be ignored in favour of the default value you supplied when assigning a closure to the handler. Again, this technically possibly, but will most likely just confuse whomever codes, and lives near the subject of *"troll coding"* (e.g. not-so-appriciated 1st april insertion into the code of a colleague, *"`handler(2,2) == 4 // false ?!?`"*). Anyway:

```
func completionHandler(value: Int, _ value2: Int) {
    print(value + value2)
}

func defaultValueHandler(defaultValue: Int? = nil, defaultValue2: Int? = nil) -> ((Int, Int) -> ()) {
    if let defaultValue2 = defaultValue2 {
        if defaultValue == nil {
            return { value, _ in completionHandler(value, defaultValue2) }
        }
    }
    else if let defaultValue = defaultValue {
        return { _, value2 in completionHandler(defaultValue, value2) }
    }
    return { _ in print("Invalid use: supply a single non-nil default value.") }
}

var handler = defaultValueHandler(9)
handler(0,5) // ignores first parameter '0', calls foo(9, 5), prints 14
handler = defaultValueHandler(nil, defaultValue2: 11)
handler(5,0) // ignores second parameter '0', calls foo(5, 11), prints 16
```